# Why does using .Date with EF work sometimes, but not others?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

VS 2013, EF6 Code First

I'm using this code and it works fine:

```
var timeslots = Vehicle.VehicleTimeSlots.Where(t =>
    t.CreateDate.Date <= currentDate.Date
    && (t.DeleteDate == null || t.DeleteDate.Value.Date > currentDate.Date)
    && t.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek).OrderBy(t => t.StartTime);
```

However, if I try to do this I get a runtime error "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." (**db** is an instance of my DbContext):

```
var previousReservation = db.ReservationTimeSlots.SingleOrDefault(t =>
    t.ReservationDate.Date == reservationTimeslot.ReservationDate.Date
    && t.VehicleTimeSlotId == reservationTimeslot.VehicleTimeSlotId);
```

There's many other questions about this issue and I know that I can use DbFunctions.TruncateTime() in the latter bit of code (which I am now doing). I guess the difference is that the first bit of code is operating against the Vehicle entity object while the second bit of code is operating directly against the DbContext. Aren't they both LINQ to Entities though?

Comment: It is relatively easy to add support for this in Entity Framework.

Comment: A 'fix' is to store `reservationTimeslot.ReservationDate.Date` in a local variable and use that local variable in the query.  As far as the `Expression` is concerned, that value will be a constant.

Comment: I think I would still have an issue with the `t.ReservationDate.Date` even if I stored `reservationTimeslot.ReservationDate.Date` in a local variable, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question. You are right, the first query is operating against *in-memory object* (`Vehicle`) and thus you can use any property/feature.

Whereas the second LINQ expression will be translated to underlying data source language *(probably SQL)* and each expression doesn't have an equivalent translation available in entity framework.

> Aren't they both LINQ to Entities though?

No, the first one is [**LINQ to objects**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) and the second expression in LINQ to entities.